# How to test a private member with private constructor C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I have some code below:

```
class base{
private:
    base();
    int x;
public:
    friend class child;
};
class child{
public:
    void display(base* b)
    {
        b->x = 1;
    }

};
int main()
{
    base* t;
    //t = new base;
    child c;
    c.display(t);
}
```

I am not able to assign the object `t`. I would like to test the value of `x`.
How can I test this code?

Comment: `base` doesn't have an interface, so there isn't really anything to test. Your tests should verify that `child` works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You usually only test the public API of your classes.
So, if it is necessary for you to test the value of `x`, most likely that value is relevant for other classes as well. The fact that you declared `child` as friend to access `x` supports that fact.

Conclusion:
Make `x` public or (better) provide getter and possibly setter methods.

Answer (score 1):

add this code to the base class in public section:

```
friend int main();
```

and then in main function, uncomment the line which is:

```
t=new base;
```

But I recommend you to make constructor of base class public instead of private. Also, I am really curious why you made constructor of base class private.

Comment: Because I am using singleton class